# What caused the Segmentation fault?

Tags: c, visual-studio, debugging, segmentation-fault, share

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
    int n=15,i,j,c=1,arr[n/2],prime=0;
    arr[0]=2;
    for(i=3;i<=n;i+=2)
    {
       int count=0;
       for(j=2;j<(sqrt(i));j++)
       {
           if(i%j==0)
           {
           count=1;
           break;
           }
       }
       if(count==0)
       {
           arr[c]=i;
           c++;
       }
    }  
    for(i=c;i>0;i++)     
    {
        int sum=0;
        int k=arr[i];
        for(j=0;sum<=k;j++)
        {
            sum=sum+arr[j];  **segmentation error in this line**
            if(sum==k)
            {
                prime++;
                break;
            }
     }
     printf("%d",prime);
}
```

The line I have mentioned above is causing me the segmentation fault is it wrong usage of array?
as per this function the value of c is 6. The contents of arr={2,3,5,7,11,13,15} i.e  7 elements and I am using c=6 as index value.

Comment: This looks wrong to me: `for(i=c;i>0;i++) `.

Comment: The loop `for(i=c;i>0;i++)` begins with a value of `c` which is an element of `arr[]` that has not been written to (note the earlier `c++`). So when you base a loop on `k=arr[i]` the value of `k` is indeterminate.

Comment: Read  [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), then the [documentation of GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/). Enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler: with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with  `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`

Answer (score 2):

`for ( i = c; i > 0; i++ )`

`c` is at least `1`. With `i = c`, the condition `i > 0` and the (!) incrementation (not decrementation) of `i` after each iteration (`i++`) the loop goes infinite - `i` will be always greater than `0`.

The segmentation fault occurs before any other run-time error because the program attempts to access elements beyond the array `arr` by using `arr[i]` and `arr[j]` at a certain point in the infinite loop.

Try to replace `i++` with `i--` in the first place.